# Why don't 64-bit systems have syscalls like creat?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, system-calls, libc

From this commit https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/a0673fdbcd42105261646cd4f3447455b5854a32 
I learnt that there are some 32bit-spec syscalls like `creat`, which have been removed on architectures like arm64.

From the [glibc manual for creat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html):

> **creat()**
>
> A call to `creat()` is equivalent to calling `open()` with flags equal to `O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC`.

IIUC, `creat` can virtually be implemented via `open`, but I also learnt that `creat` comes after `open`. It should be more convenient to call `creat` if I want to create instead of opening a file. Of course, we can always use glibc version of create:

```
/* Create FILE with protections MODE.  */
int
__creat64 (const char *file, mode_t mode)
{
#if defined __OFF_T_MATCHES_OFF64_T && defined __NR_creat
  return SYSCALL_CANCEL (creat, file, mode);
#else
  /* We need to pass O_LARGEFILE.  */
  return __open64 (file, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, mode);
#endif
}
weak_alias (__creat64, creat64)

#ifdef __OFF_T_MATCHES_OFF64_T
strong_alias (__creat64, __creat)
weak_alias (__creat64, creat)
#endif
```

which will fade to `open syscall` if `creat syscall` is not available. But I still cannot figure out what's wrong if we still have `creat` as `syscall` in 64-bit architectures.

Comment: The [`creat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/creat.html) call is still required by POSIX, but there's no obvious reason it can't be implemented as `static inline int creat(const char *name, int mode) { return open(name, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, mode); }`.

Comment: I'm running a 64bit ubuntu linux and it has the `creat()` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`creat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/creat.html) call is still required by POSIX, but there's no obvious reason it can't be implemented as:

```
static inline int creat(const char *name, int mode)
{
    return open(name, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, mode);
}
```

Indeed, POSIX says that it should be implemented *as if* it was like that (give or take the `static inline` qualifiers).

When `creat()` was created, `open()` didn't have options to create files; it could only open existing files.  It didn't have all the `O_xyz` names; you used `0` (for `O_RDONLY`), `1` (for `O_WRONLY`) and `2` (for `O_RDWR`) — and those were all the options available.

Nowadays, with the 'variable arguments' version of [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) (yes, the third, mode argument is optional), you no longer need `creat()` — you can do it all with `open()` and then some.

There's really no need for `creat()` to be a system call separate from `open()`, therefore, and most modern code (say, code written in the current millennium) does not use `creat()` anyway.  I don't know when I last wrote code using `creat()` — it was a *long* time ago.  (I searched my source code; there were two programs still with `creat()` calls, but those calls were both in version 1.1 of the code, dated January and February 1990.  I don't have any record of having used it in my own code since then.)

Comment: I tried `creat` on amd64(x86_64) and found that it still call creat as syscall(from `strace`). https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v3.13/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl#L17 So it seems not all arch have remove these legacy calls, right?

Comment: Right. It’s not necessary except perhaps for backwards compatibility but may be there. Normally, you don’t need to worry. Write your code to use the function (or, better, to use `open()`), and let the compilation system deal with the rest.  Your 32-bit code should still compile and link, just as your 64-bit code should.  Did you actually run into a problem or are you just worried because of the check-in notes?

Comment: just out of curiosity haha

Comment: FYI, the [commit](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/a0673fdbcd42105261646cd4f3447455b5854a32) ref'd by the OP removes not only `creat(2)`, but also `open(2)` from the list of system call numbers exposed in the userland headers. Both `creat()` and `open()` could still be used, they're not removed from the kernel system calls table, it's just that programs linked against newer libraries will use __`openat(2)`__ instead (and `clone(CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD)` instead of `fork()`, etc.

Comment: @陳 力 old system calls are only kept for _binary_ compatibility. There is no point to implement deprecated system calls on a new architecture. That's why there is no `oldolduname`, `olduname`, `bdflush`, `socketcall`, etc on x86_64, because they were already deprecated when the arch was introduced, and there were no binary programs using them. `amd64` came even later and got rid of another bunch.